# Pullback along a Lax Functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, counterexamples

Consider a 2-category of bicategories, lax functors and transformations (I'm actually using double categories but the result should be the same).

Given a cospan $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{E} \leftarrow \mathbb{D}$, we can try to construct a 2-pullback, but the most obvious construction doesn't work.
Specifically if we try to make arrows in the pullback consist of arrows in $\mathbb{C},\mathbb{D}$ and an equivalence between them in $\mathbb{E}$, we won't be able to compose them because we need the lax composition cells to be invertible.

You *can* easily construct a comma object from the cospan if the source is oplax and the target is lax, and using the same construction you can make a 2-pullback if both are pseudofunctors.

This is explained with some nice diagrams in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08100

However, this just shows that the most obvious construction doesn't work, is there a concrete counterexample that shows there is *no* 2-pullback of some cospan of 2-categories where one side is lax? Even better if the other arrow is pseudo.